# How to Add Google Adwords Conversio tracking Code to CK form in joomla?

Tags: google-ads-api

How i can add the Google Adword Conversion Code to Joomla Site? Here there is a form here created with CK form extension, after submitting data it will go to Thank You page. And i want to add the Google Adword Conversion Tracking Code in this page. How i can do that?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that whether my method is most accurate and simple.

I've created many 'thanks pages' for different ckforms, and use each page as the result page URL in each form.

Then, I am using php code in Template index file to judge whether this page comes out, if one 'thanks page' is showing, the tracking code for the related form would be outputted before the end of the body.

CODE like this:

```
<?php if(JRequest::getVar('id')==XXXXXX){?>
    <!-- Google Code for Contact Us Page Form Completion Conversion Page -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - your tracking code here - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    </noscript>
<?php }?>
```

Hope can help you guys.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this in joomla 1.5 and it works.
This are the steps you have to do.

1) Go to Global Configuration under Site menu.

2) Make Default Editor None and then click on Save and Close Button.

3) Click on Module Manager under Extension Menu.

4) Create a New Module on clicking New Button. When you click on New Button a popup will appear on the screen, select Custom HTML.

5) Give a Title for this module, Set position Debug, and at last not least assign the module to the pages you want to track. In Custom Text Field you can paste your Adword code.

6 )At Last click on save and close. By this Joomla will not clean your Script tag until you will not make any change in it after changing the default editor.
Your Google Adword Conversion Code has be successfully setup.

After that you can go again to Global Configuration and set again your preferable editor,save and close.

It's not my idea,i found it here,https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140729101150-347831273-how-to-add-google-adword-conversion-code-to-joomla-site

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.